# Why is my script not generating any change when I click my button element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<section>
<div class="col-md-6">
<button id="quoteClick" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg 
quoteButton text-center btn-block">Get Quote</button>
</div>
</section>

<section> 

<div class="col-md-8 boxed show text-center">
          Text
          </div>  
</section>
```

I want to click the button and have my text change so I have the following code within my html file:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#quoteClick").on("click", function(){

      $(".show").html("Here is the message");

    });
  });
</script>
```

The button displays correctly however, when I click it nothing happens.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hmurpLs7/ working fine.

Comment: Did you forget to include jQuery?

Comment: Is `html` appended to `document` dynamically?

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: I can see it works in the fiddle link. Still not working for me. I'm using codepen, is there maybe an option I should "switch on" so that it reads the javascript portion?

Comment: @abagshaw what do you mean include jQuery?

Comment: You are using jQuery functions. If you haven't included the jQuery source in your HTML file then you're going to have problems. See https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: Ok,@abagshaw, got it. Did it. I'm an idiot.. it works now. Thanks everyone

Comment: If jQuery is included then this should work. $(document).on('click', 'button#quoteClick', function(){ // do your code here })'